# (Tabulator - editor - progress) progress it is not possible to set the value equal to 100%

Tags: tabulator

I noticed that if you use editor - progress it is not possible to set the value equal to 100%.
The same behavior is on the demo page in the "Examples" section - "Editable Data".
What do you recommend to do with this?
[example from demo page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRB16.png)

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in older versions of Tabulator.

The problem was fixed in the 4.9 release.